# Query JDBC Java

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a problem with my java/jdbc code.

parameter index out of range (2 number of parameters which is 1)

Code:

```
                Connection c = null;
                MySQL MySQL = new MySQL(Host, Port, Database, Username, Password);
                c = MySQL.open();  
              Player player = (Player) sender;
               String zapytanie = "UPDATE `?` SET `tag`=? WHERE   `name`='?';";
               PreparedStatement ps = c.prepareStatement( zapytanie );
               ps.setString(1, Tabel);
               ps.setString(2, red);
               ps.setString(3, player());
               ps.executeUpdate(); //Executes the query
               ps.close(); //Closes the query
               c.close();
```

Comment: Could this have something to do with the ` quote marks?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
final String zapytanie = "UPDATE " + Table + " SET tag = ? WHERE name = ?";
```

- No quotes around `?` required
- JDBC doesn't require a `;` after *any* SQL statement
- Place holders `?` can only be used for *column values*

Comment: +1, that's exactly it.I would also suggest making your query string `final String zapytanie`

Comment: you have an error in your sql syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near ''tabelx' SET tag='red' WHERE name='Awek' '

Comment: @Awesomeness Table name would have to be concatenated. `?` applies to column values only.

Comment: Also please make sure that `Table` is not derived from user input or someone will try to update the table `SOME_TABLE SET ID=ID WHERE 1=2; DROP TABLE USERS; --`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Assuming, table name is derived from user input. Say, something like phpMyAdmin. How best to handle it?

Comment: @Awesomeness Did you mean "Guys"? :D Please, edit your comment.

Comment: @RaviThapliyal: you have to validate the table name. The safest course is probably to check if it's in a set of known-good table names.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, I was wondering if we have something built-in in Java or a third-party validation library that could `escape_sql_string()` but having a `Set` of known table names sounds even better to me. Thanks for sharing.